# Postgres Update Query

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, uuid

I'm executing below query in postgres 12.11

Table structure as below:

```
CREATE TABLE pdb_interface.schedule (
id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
report varchar NOT NULL,
users varchar NOT NULL,
"hour" int4 NULL,
min int4 NULL,
daily_frequency int4 NULL,
daily_workday bool NULL,
weekly_frequency int4 NULL,
weekly_days varchar NULL,
monthly_sected_days varchar NULL,
last_updated timestamp NULL,
deleted bool NULL,
CONSTRAINT schedule_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT schedule_report_fkey FOREIGN KEY (report) REFERENCES pdb_interface.report("Id"),
CONSTRAINT schedule_users_fkey FOREIGN KEY (users) REFERENCES pdb_interface.users("Id"));

update schedule 
  set daily_frequency = 12 
where id = 'f2f0ba60-f8b1-49ae-a82c-aaddb1a1834b'
```

The column "id" is of uuid and value is present in the table . However while executing above query, it is giving below error

**SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: no conversion function from character varying to uuid**

Is there any work around for the same

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ignore the null,it got pasted as null..made the edits

Comment: Sounds like a client-specific issue.  You will have to provide the info and code about that.  You could try explicitly casting it: `where id = 'f2f0ba60-f8b1-49ae-a82c-aaddb1a1834b'::uuid`

Comment: @jjanes: [it works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/ujBudKSe) without casting

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, on at least one client it does :)